Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules
I have created a new project with React Native version 0.75.4. I have recently done React native setup so all the dependencies are up to date.
I have created project using: npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init projectname

Node version: 22.9.0
macOS: Sequoia 15.0
Watchman version: 2024.10.14.00
OpenJDK version: "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.7",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.75.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.8",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.75.4",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.75.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
}

I have tried following solutions but none of them work:

Delete and reinstall node module
npm run start --reset-cache
npm install --save @babel/runtime
stop watchman server
also tried using yarn

I have tried installing @babel/runtime as both dev and development dependency, but none of it worked.
